How to preload common resource in a Spring Boot RestController?
I have a Controller with RequestMapping(foo/{fooId}/bar/}), FooEntity is used in all methods, how can i preload FooEntity for all the methods of FooController?
@RestController
@RequestMapping("foo/{fooId}/bar")
public class FooController {

  public void prefetchFoo(@PathVariable Long fooId) {
   ...
  }
  
  @PostMapping("/")
  public ResponseEntity<void> createFooBar(FooEntity prefetchedFoo) {
   ...
  }

 
  @GetMapping("/{barId}")
  public ResponseEntity<void> getFooBar(FooEntity prefetchedFoo) {
   ...
  }

}


I have found @ModelAttribute in my research, but i only saw it in the context of web views, is it viable to use it in the context of JSON APIs?

You can use @ModelAttribute in the context of JSON APIs. The @ModelAttribute method will be called before each request handler method and can populate the model attribute with the necessary data. This is applicable regardless of whether your API produces views or JSON responses.
@RestController
@RequestMapping("foo/{fooId}/bar")
public class FooController {
@Autowired
private FooService fooService;

@ModelAttribute
public FooEntity prefetchFoo(@PathVariable Long fooId) {
    // Logic to fetch FooEntity based on fooId
    return fooService.findFooById(fooId);
}

@PostMapping("/")
public ResponseEntity<Void> createFooBar(@ModelAttribute FooEntity prefetchedFoo) {
    ...
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}

@GetMapping("/{barId}")
public ResponseEntity<FooEntity> getFooBar(@PathVariable Long barId, @ModelAttribute FooEntity prefetchedFoo) {
   ...
    return ResponseEntity.ok(prefetchedFoo);
}
}


Easy Way
Make use of your FooService
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo/{fooId}/bar")
public class FooController {

    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService;

    @PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createFooBar(
            @PathVariable Long fooId,
            @RequestBody(required = false) SomeRequest request
    ) {
        FooEntity prefetchedFoo = fooService.getFooById(fooId);
        System.out.println(prefetchedFoo);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{barId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> getFooBar(
            @PathVariable Long fooId,
            @PathVariable Long barId
    ) {
        FooEntity prefetchedFoo = fooService.getFooById(fooId);
        System.out.println("barId " + barId);
        System.out.println(prefetchedFoo);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}

Geeky Way
Step 1: Create an annotation
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PreloadedFoo {
}

Step 2: Implement HandlerMethodArgumentResolver
HandlerMethodArgumentResolver is a Strategy interface for resolving method parameters into argument values in the context of a given request.
supportsParameter() method checks whether the given method parameter is supported by this resolver.
resolveArgument() method resolves a method parameter into an argument value from a given request.
@Component
public class FooEntityArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService;

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterAnnotation(PreloadedFoo.class) != null
                && parameter.getParameterType().equals(FooEntity.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                                  NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory
    ) throws Exception {
        // Extract path variable from the request attributes
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, String> pathVariables = (Map<String, String>) webRequest.getAttribute(
                HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);

        String fooIdParam = pathVariables != null ? pathVariables.get("fooId") : null;

        // use getParameter() if you want to pass the fooId as requestParam
        // webRequest.getParameter("requestParam");
        if (fooIdParam != null) {
            Long fooId = Long.parseLong(fooIdParam);
            return fooService.getFooById(fooId);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("fooId parameter is required");
    }
}

Step 3: Register the resolver
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private FooEntityArgumentResolver fooEntityArgumentResolver;

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
        resolvers.add(fooEntityArgumentResolver);
    }
}

Step 4: Annotate parameters in the Controller methods
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo/{fooId}/bar")
public class FooController {

    @PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createFooBar(@PreloadedFoo FooEntity prefetchedFoo,
                                             @RequestBody(required = false) SomeRequest request
    ) {
        System.out.println(prefetchedFoo);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{barId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> getFooBar(
            @PreloadedFoo FooEntity prefetchedFoo,
            @PathVariable Long barId,
            @RequestParam String requestParam
    ) {
        System.out.println("barId " + barId);
        System.out.println(requestParam);
        System.out.println(prefetchedFoo);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}

Add in comments if you need any more clarification.

The intent of prefetching it is because it will be used in all methods, so i want to avoid code repetition. What would be the differences from option 2 and using @ModelAttribute?
